# Не удается удалить запись

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста, есть таблица `messages_group` выглядит она так:

```
user_one int(11) NOT NULL,
user_two int(11) NOT NULL
hash int(11) NOT NULL
```

Есть кнопка на удаления

```
<a href='?act=delete2&ps_id=<?=$hash?>'> <img src="background/trash.png" class="hrefff"></a>
```

И сама функция удаления

```
<?php
if ($act == 'delete2') {
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM `message_group` WHERE `hash`='$hash' LIMIT 1");
}
?>
```

Вот почему то не удаляется запись, в чем ошибка? подкорректируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: $act -  это что? Суперглобалка? Если да, то лучше выключите, 2014 год на дворе все-таки ))

Comment: и delete2 лучше на что-то вменяемое заменить, сами потом не разберетесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
if ($_GET['act'] == 'delete2') {
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM `message_group` WHERE `hash`='".$hash."'");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше методом POST передавать хеш, или он гарантированно не содержит недопустимые в УРЛ символы?? Проверьте, что содержит $hash после передачи через УРЛ, например, добавив в инструкцию IF:

```
echo $hash;
```